# calculate a sum of type time using sql

Tags: sql, mysql

How to caculate sum of times of my colonne called "timeSpent" having this format: HH:mm 
in SQL? I am using MySQL.

the type of my column is Time.

it has this structure

```
TimeFrom like  10:00:00           12:00:00     02:00:00
TimeUntil      08:00:00           09:15:00     01:15:00
Time spent      

total time 03:15:00
```

Comment: RDBMS: mysql.
the query select SUM(timespent) from mytablename doen't work like i want if the sum is 02: 10:30 it is displayed 021030.

Comment: you mean u have 2 cols timefrom and time until? what is your database? `SELECT sum(DATEDIFF(minute, timeFrom,timeUntil)) from TableName`

Comment: it is caused by the type time.
it needs a specific function i don't know please help.

Comment: i think datediff is to get the difference between the 2 times not the sum as i remember

Comment: Pls update your question with the output from: `DESC your_table_name`.  I'd like to see the data type for these two columns.

Comment: yes since i have no solution and time is killing me right now.

Comment: @kawtousse: *Our* time is valuable too.  Please just update the original question instead of posting duplicates.

Answer (score 108):

```
SELECT  SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC( `timeSpent` ) ) ) AS timeSum  
FROM YourTableName
```

Comment: It took a lot of looking round the web and this was the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The maximum absolute value of a `TIME` item is `838:59:59`, or +/-
 `3020399` seconds (just under 35 days). So this answer, while correct, can overflow when you use `SEC_TO_TIME()` on the sum. The overflow is silently truncated to the maximum.  Be careful summing many time values.

Comment: Working on MySQL server 8.0.13. Just be careful of what @O.Jones says.

Comment: @O.Jones what  would be the right approach to sum TIME fields without loosing data cause the overflow issue?

Answer (score 8):

**100% working code to get sum of time out of MYSQL Database:**

```
SELECT
SEC_TO_TIME( SUM(time_to_sec(`db`.`tablename`))) 
As timeSum
FROM
`tablename`
```

Try and confirm.
Thanks.

Comment: The same answer as posted three years earlier? Why?

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would do something like this to get the time interval:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('08:00:00', '10:00:00');
```

Then to add the time intervals, you would do:

```
SELECT ADDTIME('01:00:00', '01:30:00');
```

Unfortunately, you're not storing dates or using 24-hour time, so these calculations would end up incorrect since your `TimeUntil` is actually lower than your `TimeFrom`.

Another approach would be (assuming you sort out the above issue) to store the time intervals as seconds using `TIMESTAMPDIFF()`:

```
UPDATE my_table SET time_spent=TIMESTAMPDIFF(start, end));
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(time_spent)) FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of the `timeSpent` column is `TIME` you should be able to use the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(timeSpent) 
  FROM YourTableName    -- replace YourTableName with the actual table name
```

However, if that is not the case, you may have to use a cast to convert to the `Time` data type. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT SUM(timeSpent - CAST('0:0:0' as TIME)) 
  FROM YourTableName    -- replace YourTableName with the actual table name
```

Comment: hmm.. can you post the table definition and the query that you have so far?