# how to have the right sum of type Time with sql

Tags: sql, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [calculate a sum of type time using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql)

I have 2 columns called `TimeFrom` and `TimeUntill`. The duration is calculated in `TimeSpent`.

The values in the column `TimeFrom` look like this: *10:00:00*
The values in the column `TimeUntill` look like this: *12:00:00*
The `TimeSpent` column would then have the value: *02:00:00*.

My goal is to calculate the sum of `timeSpent`.