# MySQL SUM time(3) with milliseconds

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql column time(3) and it's storing good value of time..
but then I want to sum two times it converts to bad time format;

I have two records:

```
id | time
---|-----------
1  | 00:00:15.490
2  | 00:02:14.900
```

So in real I shoud get: `00:02:30.390`

but I get `230.390`

is anyway to get correct answer from Mysql? 
P.S. I am using php for functions but dont want to use it, unless there is other way.
Need to sum times with MILLISECONDS

for now I am using query `SELECT SUM(time) AS total_time FROM times WHERE 1`

Comment: use php inbuilt function date_format().

Comment: Possible duplicate. Read this article, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054943/calculate-sum-time-with-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [calculate a sum of type time using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql)

Comment: theese your duplicates shows time sum without milliseconds.. :/ and I need with milliseconds to sum time(3)

Comment: How/where do you *sum two times*?

Comment: you would be better off storing your times as integers with millisecond resolution i think

Comment: but i dont want to store my times in miliseconds.. :? but maybe i will  do it. but still dont want

Comment: scratch that - if your mysql version is 5.6+ it's not that hard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>Provided your table definition is something like this:</s>

```
create table test (
  id integer,
  `time` time(3)   -- important to specify precision
);
```

You can do this:

```
select time(sum(`time`))
  from test;
```

**note: requires mysql 5.6+**

<s>**edit**</s>

Actually, `time` is the wrong function to use, as it doesn't have many smarts.

use `sec_to_time` instead, ie:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(`time`))
  from test;
```

`time` extracts a time value, `sec_to_time` calculates a time value -- ie, `time(70)` returns NULL because there's no valid time that has 70 seconds, where as `sec_to_time` will correctly return `'00:01:10'` for the same input

**edit**

Turns out i'm still wrong.  Lets try treating the milliseconds separately to the rest of the time:

```
select sec_to_time(sum(time_to_sec(`time`)) + sum(microsecond(`time`))/1000000)
  from test;
```

Comment: YES!!! that's what i want!! Thank you very much!! just needed time before SUM!!!! :))) I'm so happy now.. ;D

Comment: maybe you can tell me why this solution get NULL if time values that I am trying to sum is 
total_time
`00:00:19.020`, `00:00:21.990`, `00:00:30.360`

Comment: try using `sec_to_time` instead of `time`.

Comment: also i found bad sum value of sec_to_time which is 
values of `00:00:19.820`, `00:00:51.690`, `00:01:30.200`. 
it should be `00:02:41.710` but gets `00:03:21.710`

Comment: And how I understand function in MYSQL SUM is summing time format to seconds like 201.710 and that's why your answer is not fully correct :///

Comment: maybe you also know any PHP function to sort php multidimensional array with time format like this , with milliseconds? because none is working with this time format :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79495/discussion-between-scorpioniz-and-pala).

Comment: that's enough like a new question that it probably should be

Comment: Good lord, Why do they make is this difficult?

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your outputted result with the time function. So:

```
time(sum(`time`))
```

where time is the time function and 'time' is your summed column.

Comment: is it really the solution for OP.?

Comment: if he edited the post. you need to rethink, and provide other solution. otherwise you will get more -ve marking.

Comment: Rather than complaining about my answer come up with the answer for him to help him out. He only just edited his answer a few minutes ago.

Comment: I am not complaining. giving a suggestion. don't be panic.

Comment: But seriously, you can't expect me to be watching questions intently waiting in case there is an edit. You only criticized my answer about 2 minutes after he changed his question.

Comment: even still - turns out `time` is the wrong function to use because it's dumb.  i made the same mistake!