# Sum the time user spent in particular place PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My table columns are :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
| EVENT_ID | EVENT_WORKDAY | EVENT_PLACE | EVENT_TIME | EVENT_TYPE |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, it's a log of what a person did at work. What I want to do is to know how much time the person spent in a particular place.

- `EVENT_WORKDAY` is what will be pased into `WHERE` argument (I already know at which workdays he was in that place)
- `EVENT_PLACE` is an id of a place (it might be 1, 2 or 3)
- `EVENT_TIME` is a datetime field
- `EVENT_TYPE` is a type of event (1 - at some place, 2 - having a break, 3 - outside)

For example:
A person has started logging at 6:00 being outside 
`(EVENT_TYPE=3, EVENT_PLACE=null)`. Then at 6:15 moved to a place `(EVENT_PLACE=1, EVENT_TYPE=1)`, he continued to log it every 15 minutes till 9:53, when he went for a break `(EVENT_TYPE=2, EVENT_PLACE=null)`, at 10:22 he changed the place `EVENT_TYPE=1, EVENT_PLACE=2`

What I want to get is the time spent at place 1. It must be the time between first event and event at 9:53. So the output must be, that he was in place 1 for 3 hours 38 minutes (or its equivalent in minutes/seconds etc.)

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| EVENT_ID | EVENT_WORKDAY | EVENT_PLACE | EVENT_TIME          | EVENT_TYPE |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1      |   1           |    null     | 2016-04-02 06:00:00 |    3
    2      |   1           |    1        | 2016-04-02 06:15:00 |    1
    3      |   1           |    1        | 2016-04-02 06:30:00 |    1
    4      |   1           |    1        | 2016-04-02 06:45:00 |    1
          ...             ...
   15      |   1           |    1        | 2016-04-02 09:45:00 |    1
   16      |   1           |    null     | 2016-04-02 09:53:00 |    2
   17      |   1           |    2        | 2016-04-02 10:22:00 |    1
```

Comment: This questions answers might be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql

Comment: what about starting at 11:59pm on one night and finishing at 12:01am the next morning?

Comment: @MarcB yes, that might also happen

Comment: @Luke3butler the problem is that, we don't have a column with an end time like in the question linked by you. our end time is the change of EVENT_PLACE to null or something different from 1

Comment: @user3271645 I see. So using [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) would probably be a more relevant solution?