# Build array from query for a total time calculation

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code that draws the data from the db, that when run displays the time totals for each record in a hh:mm format, eg 00:35 for 35 minutes.

```
$query="SELECT * FROM data1 ORDER BY id DESC";
$result=mysql_query ($query);
$num=mysql_num_rows ($result);
mysql_close();

$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$time_ttl=mysql_result($result,$i,"time_ttl");
echo $time_ttl . "<br>";
++$i;
}
```

The result from the query looks like this:

00:35
00:25
00:10

Total time: 01:10 (1 hour 10 minutes)

Depending on the query, the number of totals will vary, and I want to calculate a grand total depending on the query.

I tried using this code to calculate the time, which works, but I am not sure how to connect the incoming data inside the 'while { }' part:

```
$times = array();

$times[] = "00:35";
$times[] = "00:25";
$times[] = "00:10";

function ttl_time($times) {

foreach ($times as $time) {
    list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);
    $minutes += $hour * 60;
    $minutes += $minute;
}

$hours = floor($minutes / 60);
$minutes -= $hours * 60;

$ttl_time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $hours, $minutes);

}
```

The code calculates the total time correctly, but I am looking for guidance how to build an array based on the query to feed into the ttl_time function so I can connect the incoming query data to the function.

I did try this:

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(time_ttl) FROM data1");
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
echo $rows['sum(time_ttl)'];
}
```

But it returns the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly...

```
$i=0; $result_times = array();
while ($i < $num) {
  $result_times[] = mysql_result($result,$i,"time_ttl");
  ++$i;
}
```

Then you can pass `$result_times` to your `ttl_time` function.

As for your other attempted solution (using `sum`) it depends on the data type. This may be helpful: [calculate a sum of type time using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I am still getting the wrong result. For example, for one client calculated manually, and with excel i get 42:48 (42 hours 48 min). Using your code I get 46:20 with the same data. Not sure why.

Comment: just checked again. i was getting fewer records on the first run. Looks like your code snip worked. thanks!

Comment: If this answer has helped you. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I tried, but it wont allow me. not enough points or something