# How to get sum of times in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How to calculate sum of times store in a column in mysql ?
table name : timesheet

```
+----------+
| hours    |
+----------+
| 02:00:00 |
| 03:30:00 |
| 04:30:00 |
| 05:30:00 |
| 06:00:00 |
| 07:00:00 |
| 08:00:00 |
| 09:00:00 |
+----------+
```

I need output : `45:30:00` .
I tried with the below sql

```
select sum(hours) from timesheet ;
```

But it is showing `449000`
can you please correct me with proper sql ?

Comment: Please check this question it might be help you [Sackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql)

Comment: `select  SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(hours))) from timesheet ;`

Comment: Yah!! it's working .Thank you very much @Damith.

Comment: @Damith, please post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz Done

Comment: @Damith, Thanks. +1

Comment: Mihir, please mark @Damith answer as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SEC_TO_TIME and TIME_TO_SEC [date time functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
select SEC_TO_TIME(sum(TIME_TO_SEC(hours))) from timesheet ;
```