# laravel - sum time from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Welcome ! I have a problem. I have database where I store notes: name, note, time of flight. Now I want to sum total time of flight of each user and display it on show page of selected user. All data are stored in one database named notes.

I tried to do something like this in Controller:

```
public function show($id)

{

    $notes = Pilot::find($id)->note()->get();

    $pilots = Pilot::find($id);

    $time = DB::table('notes')
            ->selectRaw('SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(czas))')>having('SUM(czas)')
            ->first();

    return view('dziennikpracy.show',['notes' => $notes,'pilots'=>$pilots, 'time'=>$time,]);

}
```

and display it on show page like that:

```
{{ $time }}
```

First of all it's not working. Secondly I don't know how to write method to sum time for each user so it'll count all times for user id 2, user id 3 etc etc

Thank u for help

Comment: I forgot to add: Each note belongs to user id in database

Comment: You haven't included any details about the format in which the times are actually stored.

Comment: Time is stored in database as "time" -format 00:00

Comment: Luckily, there's an edit button. Forget about the PHP/Laravel stuff for now, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate a sum of type time using sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql)

Comment: i did like this `$time= DB::table('notes')
               ->where('pilot_id', $id)
                       ->sum('time');` but i get format like this 120000 and it should be 1:20 how to get it?