# Sum multiple times produced in a query (timediff)

Tags: mysql, sql-timestamp

I have two fields:

- Initial (timestamp)
- Final (timestamp)

My query is:

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF(Final, Initial) 
    AS 'Worked Hours' 
    FROM `db_foo`
    WHERE matriculation='X' AND date='2017-yy-yy'
```

The result will be something like

```
Worked Hours    
03:34:00
02:34:00
01:00:00
[...]
```

Would it be possible to further sum those multiple timestamps, so to have the TOTAL amount of worked hours?

Example dataset (exported in csv):

```
DATE --- ID --- INITIAL --- FINAL --- MATRICULATION

2017-09-14,"29","2017-09-14 11:00:00","2017-09-14 14:34:00","4"
2017-09-14,"30","2017-09-14 17:00:00","2017-09-14 19:34:00","4"
2017-09-14,"31","2017-09-14 21:00:00","2017-09-14 22:00:00","4"
```

Desired output (it is the sum of the working times):

```
Worked Hours
07:08:00
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Provide some sample data set along with your desired result set

Comment: Done, thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the desired result you can use following query

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(
  SUM(
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Initial,Final)
  )
)
FROM `db_foo` /* WHERE clause*/;
```

To get the total sum along with previous result set you can follow below approach

```
SELECT t.*,SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(workedhours))
FROM (
  SELECT ID, TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Initial,Final)  workedhours
  FROM `db_foo`  /* WHERE clause*/
 ) t
GROUP BY ID WITH ROLLUP;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ef395f/12)

Comment: If you're going to sum times, why not `SUM(TIMEDIFF(Initial, Final))` instead of `SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,Initial,Final))`? Also, the `TIME` data has a maximum value of `838:59:59`. This query will overflow if the hours worked exceed 838 hours.

Comment: @markusk apologies but i am unbale to get your point first query sums the seconds returned by TIMESTAMPDIFF and then its formatting its now as per user's wish if OP want to get the difference returned in hours,minutes or seconds etc  SEC_TO_TIME is just for showing as formatted duration

Comment: My point is that `SEC_TO_TIME` converts the difference from `INTEGER` (seconds) to `TIME`, and `TIME` is constrained to a max value of `838:59:59`, which means you will get wrong results if the total number of hours exceed 838. As an example, `SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01') / (60 * 60)` returns 8784 (which is correct), while `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, '2016-01-01', '2017-01-01'))` returns the wrong result `838:59:59`.

Comment: Thank you both, now I can solve my issue and feed the output via AJAX.

Answer (score 3):

The `TIME` type has a maximum value of `838:59:59`. If you think the sum might exceed 838 hours, it's not safe to sum `TIME` expressions. I would recommend instead converting the time differences to minutes and displaying the total number of hours as a decimal number, rather than a time:

```
SELECT
  ROUND(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, Initial, Final) / 60.0), 1) AS "Worked Hours"
FROM `db_foo`
WHERE matriculation='X' AND date='2017-yy-yy';
```

which would return

```
Worked Hours
7.1
```

Comment: Also i see no difference in your approach which is same as mine except you are calculating difference in minutes

Comment: The difference in my approach is that it works if the total number of hours exceeds 838.

Comment: Thank you, your approach is definitely smart. The table will be refreshed at midnight, so that the value will not exceed 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

used [SEC_TO_TIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sec-to-time) and [TIME_TO_SEC](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec) .

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(Final, Initial))))
AS 'Worked Hours' 
FROM `db_foo`
WHERE matriculation='X' AND date='2017-yy-yy'
```

I hope it will help you.