# can we use sum of in group_concat in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have one table, from this I want to get three columns. such as user_id,entry_date,time_duration. From this query, i want to get the employee's sum (time duration) in day wise.

my table structure is -

[image]

my expected result is -

[image]

my query and what i am getting is

[image]

how can i get my actual result?

Comment: Instead of sum, cast as char and do another group_concat.

Comment: @jarlh .can i get sample for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can aggregate twice here.  First, aggregate by person and date to generate the sum of times.  Then aggregate a second time by person only, and generate CSV output for the dates and sum of times.

```
SELECT
    sno,
    GROUP_CONCAT(entry_date ORDER BY entry_date) AS entry_dates,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CAST(sum_time AS CHAR(50)) ORDER BY entry_date) AS sum_times
FROM
(
    SELECT sno, entry_date,
       SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(time_duration))) AS sum_time
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY sno, entry_date
) t
GROUP BY sno;
```

Note that if you want to sum times, we need to do some work.  One option is to convert time to seconds, sum, then convert seconds back to time.  I do [not take credit for figuring out this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054123/calculate-a-sum-of-type-time-using-sql).

Follow the demo link below to see the query in action using the sample data provided by the question.

### Demo

Comment: i tried this query but i am getting error.., this type of clause was previously parsed

Comment: @KarthickAnbazhagan My query is working fine with your sample data.  I suggest that maybe you have some other problem on your end.